# System.IO.FileNotFoundException for assembly during unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm performing a unit test on a small library I built and it is rooted in the bin\debug-folder for the specific project. It should be properly linked as I've added a reference to the .dll-file but still when I perform the test it throws a FileNotFoundException as specified above. I've ensured that I've written `using Game;` (as the namespace is called) in top of the test file.

The error points to the opening curly bracket of the test method.

Folder structure for the library is as follows:

```
-> Projects
    -> Card
        -> Card
            -> bin
                -> Debug
                    -> Card.dll
```

For the CardTest.dll

```
-> Projects
    -> CardTest
        -> CardTest
            -> bin
                -> Debug
                    -> CardTest.dll
```

Comment: You actually referenced the DLL and not the project you want to test?

Comment: Because it says it needs a component-file which is .dll, .tlb, .olb, .ocx, .exe, and .manifest.

Comment: Do you have Card.dll in CardTest\bin\Debug ?

Comment: No. As specified above it is Card.dll is in Projects\Card\Card\bin\Debug\Card.dll whereas CardTest.dll is in Projects\CardTest\CardTest\bin\Debug\CardTest.dll.

I've found on MSDN that it was one way of doing it: straight from the folder where .dll is built.

Comment: Ok, but did you add reference to the Card project in your CardTest project? If I do so I'll find Card.dll in the CardTest Debug folder...

Answer (score 0):

Either of these methods might help you solve your problem.

1. Catch the "System.IO.FileNotFound" exception at the time that it occurs

   - Under "Debug->Exceptions"
   - Check "Common Language Runtime->System.IO->System.IO.FileNotFound"
   - The debugger will stop when it initially happens (first-chance).
2. Use the free Sysinternals "Process Monitor".

   - Set for file system activity only.
   - Add a filter for your test exe and the VS host process exe.
   - Add a filter for the result "is not SUCCESS"

Comment: How the heck am I supposed to catch and error occuring at the opening bracket of a method?...